# Why do pythons tkinter grid buttons stretch when a label in the grid changes size?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a simple application with 1 button and 1 label where pressing the button changes the text on the label. Both label and button and placed using the tkinter's grid system however when I press the button the label's text changes size as expected but the button becomes stretched to the label's length too. Why?
This is my code.

```
import tkinter as tk
def change():
    label1.config(text = "example text that is really big which shows the button stretching")
window = tk.Tk()
window.config(bg="black")
b1=tk.Button(window,text="button1",font=("Segoe UI",40),command=change).grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="news")
label1=tk.Label(text = "text",font=("Segoe UI",20),bg="black",fg="white")
label1.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky="news")
window.mainloop()
```

The expected result was the label changing and the button's size staying the same but instead the button becomes stretched to the labels length. I have tried a lot of things trying to make this work but I can't figure it out.
[Before pressing the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0pnX.png)
[After pressing the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pb23.png)

Comment: It is because you have specified `sticky="news"`, so the button will be expanded to fill the available space of the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `sticky="news"` for the button, will expand the button to fill the available space in the four directions North, East, West, South. Try changing it to `sticky="w"` to make it stick to the West. So, the line of code for creating the button will become:

```
b1=tk.Button(window,text="button1",font=("Segoe UI",40),command=change).grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="w")
```

[image]

Comment: This works but I have another script where several buttons need to be sticky to eachother in the grid and there's a label below which it which stretches the buttons, I tried several directions but can't get it to work.

[Your method](https://ibb.co/sgnz61n)
[Before](https://ibb.co/3vjpTwh)

In my code I changed +, 7, 0, 4, 1's stickiness to "e".